# When a server has multiple cerificates, which certificate has the public key?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate

I wanted to have the public key of a server. The team managing the server said to me that i can extract the certificates using openssl e.g. with command

```
openssl s_client -connect hostAddress.org:443 -showcerts
```

and this certificate will have the public key.

Using the above command, i get 3 certificates. The full output of the command is:

```
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Assured ID Root CA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=CZ/L=Praha/O=CESNET/CN=hostAddress
   i:/C=NL/ST=Noord-Holland/L=Amsterdam/O=TERENA/CN=TERENA SSL CA 3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      SOME TEXT 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=NL/ST=Noord-Holland/L=Amsterdam/O=TERENA/CN=TERENA SSL CA 3
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      SOME TEXT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Assured ID Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
       SOME TEXT
-----END CERTIFICATE-------
Server certificate
subject=/C=CZ/L=Praha/O=CESNET/CN=hostAddress
issuer=/C=NL/ST=Noord-Holland/L=Amsterdam/O=TERENA/CN=TERENA SSL CA 3
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5097 bytes and written 489 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    Session-ID: 5B9A6ACCEFE2608E33AEE1FAF8F3136A7C41D081416F885613A0C48A4D9556CD
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 83D7239981A232F1AB175F2F4980B1D6B7B1D4109878022A8FE8B3D2CD95F14D33AB2112E5F27CD1D508CE3D5EE34854
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1536846540
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

**From these 3 certificates, how do i know which one has the public key for the host?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate labelled 0 is the server certificate.  The certificate labelled 1 is the certificate for the Certificate Authority (CA) which issued the server certificate, (and so on, ) up to the last one (the somewhat standard "2"), which is the root certificate where "oh, I trust this" was established.

So, you're looking for the first one.

Comment: 1) Is this certificate in PEM format? i think so because of "begin certificate" and "end certificate" strings in it. 
2) Do i save it in a file as .cer extension or as a .pem extension? I want to extract .der public key from it.

Comment: 1) Yep. 2) Either.  Personally, I'd use .cer